# Database design for meeting room availability and booking

Tags: python, mysql, flask, database-design, architecture

I am trying to create a scheduling system for our office meeting rooms.
currently we have three meeting rooms, each one in a different size , different floor and not all of them are available the entire week ( for example between 12:00 - 14:00 one of them operates as a dining hall )

my current problem is how to represent the time table for each room i.e

```
Meeting room 1
capacity: 16 ( how many people can fit )
available:
Monday: 8:00-12:00 , 14:00-18:00
Tuesday: 8:00-12:00 , 14:00-18:00
..
..
Sunday: UNAVAILABLE.
```

so in our office management system ( python-flask ) im having hard time figuring out how to build and represent the database tables ( MySQL ) and how to design my code.

any suggestion / guidance will be appreciated

Comment: So you can see that you have a table of rooms, with capacities, and a table of days and times

Comment: There are several Q&A about "meeting room scheduling" on stackoverflow and dba.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

[ERD of your solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARrVP.png)

You will need a ternary junction table. Many rooms are available for many days and for many hours. Foreign keys from the Room, Day, and Time tables to make each record unique. If a day/time compound key is not listed for a room, default is "Not available".

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.